# Angular Eslint not working - just high disc usage without any output

Tags: angular, eslint, lint, ng

Every time I try to run eslint via commandline `ng lint` nothing happens. The commandline freezes and my disc usage jumps up as far as even possible. Sometimes reading up to 1000MB/sec.

It worked a few weeks ago and I do not really know what changed. Maybe it was an update on Angular 16 but even older projects don't work anymore.

I'm using the latest version of Jetbrains Webstorm on Windows 10. But even directly after a system restart it is not working.

Here are my package.json, angular.json and .eslintrc.json.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "2.0.8",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "16.1.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "keycloak-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^21.1.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.4",
    "pdfjs-dist": "3.4.120",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^16.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.6.1",
    "xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.20.0/xlsx-0.20.0.tgz",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.1.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "16.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "12.12.29",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.7",
    "eslint": "^8.40.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^47.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/upload.php",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "keycloak-js",
              "ng2-pdf-viewer"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/upload.php"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics",
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:unicorn/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case",
            "type": "element"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase",
            "type": "attribute"
          }
        ],
        "no-var": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "warn"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Hopefully someone can spot my problem.